# how to apply transparency to a bufferd image java

Tags: java, transparency, bufferedimage

I am trying to paint make a method that takes a bufferedImage, makes it semi-transparent, then returns the resulting bufferedImage. From there I can paint it later. However my code is failing to paint anything. Think I'm close...

```
public BufferedImage ApplyTransparency(BufferedImage image)
{
    BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(overlay1.getWidth(), overlay1.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D g3 = dest.createGraphics(); 
    AlphaComposite ac = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.DST_IN, 0.9F);
    g3.setComposite(ac);
    g3.drawImage(overlay1, 0, 0, null);

    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can draw the image onto a new image adjusting its transparency as follows

```
public Raster transform(Image img, float alpha) {
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    bi.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    RasterOp rop = new RescaleOp(new float[] { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alpha }, new float[] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }, null);
    Raster result = rop.filter(bi.getData(), null);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I managed to figure out why my code didn't work. It need the AlphaComposite flag to be DST_OVER or SRC_OVER instead of DST_IN. Don't know what the advantage of using a Raster has over a BufferedImage as Ive never used one myself. But cool to see the RescaleOp.